# Replacing space with a character

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace all the spaces in a dataframe column with a period. ie:

Original df:

```
    symbol
0   AEC
1   BRK A
2   BRK B
3   CTRX
4   FCE A
```

Desired result df:

```
    symbol
0   AEC
1   BRK.A
2   BRK.B
3   CTRX
4   FCE.A
```

Is there a way to do this without needing to iterate through each row, replacing the space one at a time? I prefer not to iterate one row at a time if there is a vectorized way to do things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use vectorised [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
In [95]:
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].str.replace(' ','.')
df

Out[95]:
  symbol
0    AEC
1  BRK.A
2  BRK.B
3   CTRX
4  FCE.A
```